# Linux grep or find files with nonprintable special character - record separator

Tags: linux, grep, find, special-characters

Some files have "file separator" and "record separator" characters in them. I'd like to list the files with them. A record separator is character 28, 1E in hex, or just RS. It's not like one of the printable characters that can be escaped. It's also not like line feeds or tabs with \n and \t respectively.

How would I grep or find files with record separator characters?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. Please let me know what I can do to make this better.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Well, typically I would use "grep -Rl <some string> ." However, there is no character. Looking at the file in vi it looks like "^^". But /^^ doesn't work in vi or grep as the search string. Notepad++ shows the character as a white RS on a black background, but that doesn't work in grep either. I found a number of posts where people used grep with the -F option to find \t tabs and \n line feeds, but I haven't found any resources that list a similar escape symbol for record and file separators.

Comment: If I type this in vi it does highlight correctly: /[\x1E]

Comment: @MrGoodfix Under bash, try `grep -rI $'\x1e'`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: This is an old server. I just ran grep --version and it's at 2.6.3. I wonder if that's why your script isn't working for me.

Comment: @MrGoodfix Are you sure you are running this under Bash? `$'..'` is a bash feature and not a `grep` feature. I would also drop the `I` in case other binary characters leads `grep` to believe the file isn't text and therefore silently excludes it.

Comment: Nice, I stripped the i option out and it worked. The working command was "grep -r $'\x1E' ." ... Go ahead and post as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess I figured it out on my own.

```
grep -Rl -E "[\x1E]" .
```

Comment: Try `echo x | grep -E "[\x1E]"` and you'll find that `[\x1E]` does not match hex 1e.  Instead it matches any of the characters backslash, `x`, `1`, or `E`.